# How to make loading route with store.all in ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application I am preloading all necessary models just after user log in. Everything works great except the fact that loading route is not working when I am calling `store.all` instead of `store.find`.

```
App.PhrasesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ->
        return @store.all("phrase")
```

Model `Phrase` have a lot of records (sometimes even one thousand) and each of them is displayed inside handlebars's each loop. It takes about half of second. User sees in this time only short lag.

The problem doesn't occurs when I am fetching all the data from server each time route is invoked by user.

```
App.PhrasesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ->
        return @store.find("phrase")
```

**I suppose that store.all is not returning any promise. How can I return it from `store.all` or deley returning model manually?**

Comment: How do you `warmup` your store? `all` only returns records which are already loaded to the store and does not perform further network requests.

Comment: Yes, `store.all` is not making any requst. Anyway, there is a lag and I need to get rid of it.

Comment: 500ms rendering time for 1000 elements is absolutely common I would say, at least with handlebars. http://jsbin.com/vevaz/1/edit . As soon as @ebryn finishes htmlbars the time will drop. Until then you could show the users a loading notification.

Comment: If I would make loading ember way I would need to reload whole model each time user hits given route? There isn't any way to make it around? Let's say manually render loading route for fixed 1 second in the time of loading expected route?

Comment: To reduce network requests warm up your `store` and use `.all()` in your subroutes. See: http://jsbin.com/vevaz/3/edit .

Comment: Please notice: Regardless of the network requests there still will be a lag of ~500ms for 1000+ elements.

Comment: No, you are wrong. With network request (using `store.find`) there isn't any lag. I can see loading route and that's the point. I want to achieve the same effect without next requests (using `store.all`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57578/discussion-between-oliver-and-estshy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
App.PhrasesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
  model: function() {
    var self = this;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
      Ember.run.later(this, function() {
        resolve(self.store.all('phrase'));
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you very much! :)